# How generalizes (automate) recursive code

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, code-review, code-generation, automation

This is a small version of my code (for n=2):

```
V0 = {{{3, 3, 2, 2}}};
S0 = {{{1, 2, 0, 4}}, {{0, 3, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 0, 3}}, {{1, 2, 1, 2}}};
S1 = Join @@@ Tuples[{S0, V0}];
S2 = Pick[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S1, 
   MatrixRank[#] == 2 & /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S1];
S3 = Join @@@ Tuples[{S0, S2}];
S4 = Pick[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S3, 
   MatrixRank[#] == 3 & /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S3];
S5 = Join @@@ Tuples[{S0, S4}];
S6 = Pick[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S5, 
   MatrixRank[#] == 4 & /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S5];
MatrixForm /@ S6
```

As you can see, it repeats the action of joining the matrices with the last set, deleting the duplicates and picking those with maximal rank. The final result is a set of 4×4 matrices. In general, for a given $n\in\Bbb N$, I have to manually write $2(n^n-1)$ lines. Is there I way to automate this procedure?

**The aim of the code:** Obtain the set of all invertible matrices with `{3,3,2,2}` as the first line and elements of `S0` as the other ones.

I could generate the the set of $3\times4$ matrices formed by elements of `S0` and then `Prepend`the vector `{3,3,2,2}` to each one, but the task "pick those with rank 4" (or "with non null determinant") is harder for the computer. Because of this, I add one line per time and take out those matrices whose rank is not maximal. The example above is very easy, but for sets with 1 million matrices, calculate the rank of each one may take a while.

Comment: You may find `Fold` or `Nest` helpful, but to help further, could you explain in words what you are trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: @MarcoB Just added to the OP. Tell me if there is something more that deserves a better explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
f[S0_, {i_, V0_}] := Module[{S1, S2},
  S1 = Join @@@ Tuples[{S0, V0}];
  S2 = Pick[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S1, MatrixRank[#] == i & /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S1];
  {i + 1, S2}
  ]

MatrixForm /@ Last@Nest[f[S0, #] &, {2, V0}, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please help me to understand your code? I want to know for example what makes the action repeat and what makes it stop. In the case of matrices $9\times9$, what I have to change in your code? I am really new on Mathematica, so I am not understanding the `Module` Documentation. Is there a place with better explained examples about module?

Comment: @Fil, why not try plugging in a matrix and vector with appropriate dimensions yourself? Note that C. E.'s code *never* needed to determine the dimensions of the matrices involved. As for `Module[]`: if you're writing functions for personal use, you'll use it a lot to encapsulate an algorithm and localize any intermediate variables used.

Comment: @J.M. But for bigger dimensions, you have to repeat more times those two lines inside `Module`. As I wrote in the OP, for $n\in\Bbb N$ there will be $2(n^n-1)$ lines. If this code put two lines each time, so we will have to tell him to repeat $n^n-1$ times. It corresponds to the number 3 inside `Nest`, isn't it? ($2^2-1$)

Comment: In that case, @Fil, then the responsibility of determining the right dimensions is on you and not on C. E.'s routine, no? I'm only saying that C. E. had written his routine to be independent of dimensions. So, if you'll be doing anything before or after this routine that is dimension-dependent, then that's your call.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I see it. I was just asking for help to understand the code, like what is the rule of the numbers 2 and 3 in the `Nest` scope. I don't think that the number 2 will change (just the number 3) to fit my aim. I read the documentation again and again and now think I understood the sufficient. I will run my full code with the changes I have in mind before I go to sleep (it will take the whole night). Tomorrow I'll see if I am right. I hope so.

Comment: @Fil, The `2` in the last line is just the desired rank. If you look at the code for `f[]`, note that the argument `i` corresponds to what is being compared with `MatrixRank[]`. In `Nest[]`, this is passed along to `f[]`. (Recall that `Nest[f, x, 3]` is another way to write `f[f[f[x]]]`.)